# Removing columns from array based on contents of specific row

Tags: python, numpy

I have this array:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[12,1,2,14],[75,10,100,53]])
array([[  12,  1,   2,   14],
       [  75,  10, 100,  53]])
```

I want to clean my data. For example, I want to keep only columns where a given row is > x.

For row `0` and `x = 1`, the expected output would be:

```
array([[  12,   2,  14],
       [  75, 100,  53]])
```

For row `1` and `x = 60`, would be the output

```
array([[  12,   2],
       [  75, 100]])
```

What would be a vectorized way of doing this?

Comment: I think there is a typo in the first line of code.  Should it be: `arr = np.array([[12,1,2,14],[75,10,100,53]])`?

Comment: Thanks for noticing it. I just corrected it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a mask. For the first case:

```
mask = arr[0] > x1
result = arr[:, mask]
```

For the second case:

```
mask = arr[1] > x2
result = arr[:, mask]
```

Both cases can be one-liners:

```
arr[:, arr[0] > x1]
```

OR

```
arr[:, arr[1] > x2]
```